# java.lang.IllegalArgumentExceptionIllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null

Tags: android, android-sqlite, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to access and display the details stored in the database by fetching through the cursor.getString() and setting it to Textview.
I'm kinda stuck doing so and  help me out

Databasehelper.java

```
public Cursor checkduplicates_in_user_credentials(String user_name, String password, String table) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = null;

        if (table.equals(TABLE_NAME_USER)) {
            res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME_USER  + " where username=? and password=? ", new String[]{user_name, password},null);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Error while running app

```
    Process: com.example.instacure, PID: 11556
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.instacure/com.example.instacure.Personal_Info}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:167)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:203)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1400)
        at com.example.instacure.DatabaseHelper.checkduplicates_in_user_credentials(DatabaseHelper.java:72)
        at com.example.instacure.Personal_Info.onCreate(Personal_Info.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is where it is referencing to

PersonalInfo.java

```
 Cursor y = db.checkduplicates_in_user_credentials(username, password, getResources().getString(R.string.user_credentials));


        if (y.moveToFirst()) {
            String name1 = y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("first_name"));
            String name2 = y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("last_name"));

            name.setText(name1+" "+name2);
            age.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("age")));
            email.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("e_mail")));
            pwd.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("password")));
            usrname.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("username")));
            phoneno.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("phone_number")));
            bloodgroup.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("blood_group")));
            gender.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("gender")));
            city.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("city")));
            utype.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("user_type")));


        }
```

Comment: What is the value of this: "getResources().getString(R.string.user_credentials)", can you print it? It should be the value of the table name, you know that? if that value contains "?" this would cause such illegal argument exception because it expects 3 parameters, and you sent string[ ] with only 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 2 is null` is telling you that the **password** is **null** and therefore cannot be used to replace (the **bind**) the **?** in the query.

You need to either ensure that the password is never null when it is obtained or to handle it being null.

The correct fix should be the first *(the code for obtaining the password is not provided so this fix cannot be given)*. However the following (handle it being null) could get around the underlying issue :-

```
public Cursor checkduplicates_in_user_credentials(String user_name, String password, String table) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = null;
    if (password == null) password = "apassswordthatwouldneverbeusedbytheuser";
    if (table.equals(TABLE_NAME_USER)) {
        res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME_USER  + " where username=? and password=? ", new String[]{user_name, password},null);
    }
    return res;
}
```

However, may still have issue as the invoking code does not handle a null Cursor which could happen if the table does not equal TABLE_NAME_USER.

So you should have something like :-

```
    Cursor y = db.checkduplicates_in_user_credentials(username, password, getResources().getString(R.string.user_credentials));

    if (y != null && y.moveToFirst()) { // will not try to moveToFirst if the Cursor is null
        String name1 = y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("first_name"));
        String name2 = y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("last_name"));

        name.setText(name1+" "+name2);
        age.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("age")));
        email.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("e_mail")));
        pwd.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("password")));
        usrname.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("username")));
        phoneno.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("phone_number")));
        bloodgroup.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("blood_group")));
        gender.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("gender")));
        city.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("city")));
        utype.setText(y.getString(y.getColumnIndex("user_type")));
    }
```

Now that you are handling the null Cursor then instead of having the potential inadvertent access should the password actually be ***apassswordthatwouldneverbeusedbytheuser*** then you could instead use :-

```
public Cursor checkduplicates_in_user_credentials(String user_name, String password, String table) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = null;
    if (password == null) return null;
    if (table.equals(TABLE_NAME_USER)) {
        res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME_USER  + " where username=? and password=? ", new String[]{user_name, password},null);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: it works but not able to fetch data from database its,empty

Comment: @NISCHALND You should, as the answer apparently fixed the issue raised in the question, tick the answer. If you have other issues, then you should ask another question. As for no data, there are numerous possibilities, but did you read the answer fully especially **The correct fix should be the first (the code for obtaining the password is not provided so this fix cannot be given).** If you didn't pass a valid password for a userid that exists then you will get no data.